# migrate to jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Let me make this same command in jQuery

```
$('aplicacao').filterByTagName(searchValue);
```

currently is in prototype would like to see more on jQuery

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#aplicacao ' + searchValue);
```

And, thanks to mkoistinen:

```
$(searchValue, '#aplicacao');
$('#aplicacao').find(searchValue);
```

These two options are better if you'd like to avoid hacking strings together, but the first is better if you want to follow CSS conventions.

Comment: Also, `$(searchValue, '#aplicacao');` and `$('#aplicacao').find(searchValue);`.

Comment: @mkoistinen Yep, both good as well. Mind if I add them in to the answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#aplicacao').find(searchValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not a pro on protorype and so, not sure what aplicacao refers to, but if it would be an id:

```
$('#aplicacao').find('h1');
```

(for example)

Comment: was not my code has another command so

aplicacao.filterByTagName(tag);